# Help with Using Checkboxes to Open a Table

Tags: input

Using MMA 12.2

MMA offers a very nice table associated with each of the planets. Here is the code as an example:

```
Entity["Planet", "Neptune"]["Dataset"]
```

Here is the table it produces:

[image]

What I want to accomplish is:

- Create checkboxes for each of the planets
- All blank initially
- Upon having one 'checked', it launches the code that produces the table (above)
- Further, have secondary selections either overwrite the first or delete it and load the new one

This does not HAVE to be done using checkboxes. It seemed low-profile in appearance and the first thing that came to my mind.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
DynamicModule[{selectedPlanet = None}, 
Column[{CheckboxBar[
Dynamic[selectedPlanet], {"Saturn", "Mars", "Neptune"}], 
Button["Open Dataset", 
If[selectedPlanet === None, 
MessageDialog["Please select a planet."], 
Entity["Planet", selectedPlanet]["Dataset"] // Print], 
Method -> "Queued"]}]]
```

It works. It is not very appealing, but the table it brings up is void of any data other than the row 'headings'.

Here is the checkbox:

[image]

Here is the table:

[image]

I am stuck.

Comment: `Entity["Planet", selectedPlanet[[1]]]["Dataset"]`

    seems to work.

Comment: @Rabbit - Yes, that works, and thanks, but do you why? What is that extra bit of code doing?

Comment: @Rabbit - Put your answer up. Will chose this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Entity["Planet", selectedPlanet[[1]]]["Dataset"]` instead of `Entity["Planet", selectedPlanet]["Dataset"]`
The value of "selectedPlanet" is, for example, `{Mars}`, that is, a list. By adding the Part specification, we get `Mars` - not a list.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at that specifically. Maybe I can advance my understanding some. Than you again. Sure appreciate it as I have spent a lot of time trying to get this to work.

Comment: @fiz   Thank you for the accept.

Comment: No problem, you got it!